# Access a variable from outside of the function that it's declared in

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

Is there a way to access a variable outside of the function that it's declared in?

```
var checkWidth = function () {
  var $width = $(window).width();
}

$(window).on('resize', checkWidth);

// access $width here with the value from the resize
```

**Solution:**

```
var $width = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function () {
  var $resizeWidth = $(window).width();

  updateWidth($resizeWidth);

});

function updateWidth(a) {
  width = a;

  // use the new width here
}
```

Comment: Just put the `var $width` declaration outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can in this way:

```
var width;

var checkWidth = function () {
    width = 150;
}

checkWidth();
console.log(width);
```

width will be 150 in the logs

Comment: Yes this works but is there a way to access it's new value from the resize event, without reloading the page?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways, actually.

You could declare it outside of the function to set its scope there, like this:

```
var $width;
var checkWidth = function () {
  $width = $(window).width();
}

$(window).on('resize', checkWidth);
```

Or, you could just omit the declaration to give it global scope:

```
var checkWidth = function () {
  $width = $(window).width();
}

$(window).on('resize', checkWidth);
```

Either way, you'll now be able to access it outside of the function, and its value will be `undefined` until you call the function.

(With that second one, you might get a `ReferenceError` due to ES5: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it).)

Answer (score 0):

The $width variable only exists within the scope of your checkWidth function.  You must declare this variable in the global scope before invoking checkWidth() if you would like to access it outside of that checkWidth scope.